# Find different combinations from two lists

Tags: python, list

Given two lists of any length, I want to find all possible combinations between the two lists and then add a dictionary pair of the combination in the new list.

For example, the two lists are:

`List1` - `['A', 'B']`

`List2` - `[1, 2]`

The resultant list should have the values:

```
[{'A':1, 'B':1}, {'A':1,'B':2}, {'A':2, 'B':1}, {'A':2, 'B':2}]
```

All the solutions I found were just giving the possible combinations. So, suppose I have a list of length 3 and 2. The possible combinations would have only 6 values. But, according to my requirement, there would be 8 values.

The code I used:

```
first_list = ['A', 'B', 'C'] 
second_list = [1, 2]
 
combinations = [(a,b) for a in first_list for b in second_list]
```

For which the output comes as:

```
[('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 1), ('C', 2)]
```

While the output I want is:

```
[{'A':1, 'B':1, 'C':1},
 {'A':1, 'B':1, 'C':2},
 {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':1},
 {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':2},
 {'A':2, 'B':1, 'C':1},
 {'A':2, 'B':1, 'C':2},
 {'A':2, 'B':2, 'C':1},
 {'A':2, 'B':2, 'C':2}]
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: These aren't combinations so much as elements of the Cartesian product. Thus, you could use `itertools.product`. Also -- the requirement that would lead to 8 rather than 6 "combinations" is obscure. Please clarify. Why not use an example with the intended output for 3 and 2?

Comment: You have edited it, but your unspecified requirement which leads to an intended output of 8 elements in the `(3,2)` case rather than 6 is still obscure. What is the actual intended output for your example?

Comment: I have edited the required output as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` to create part of the combinations:

```py
from itertools import product

first_list = ['A', 'B', 'C'] 
second_list = [1, 2]

out = product(second_list, repeat=len(first_list))

combinations = [{f:s for (f,s) in zip(first_list, c)} for c in out]

print(combinations)
```

Output as required.

Comment: I'm also converting the second part to a nested list comprehension.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll also make these changes. (Yes en(..) was a typo).

Answer (score 0):

You should look up [here](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-get-all-unique-combinations-of-two-lists-in-python)

You can use

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
list2 = [1, 2]
all_combinations = []

list1_permutations = itertools.permutations(list1, len(list2))
Get all permutations of `list1` with length 2

for each_permutation in list1_permutations:
    zipped = zip(each_permutation, list2)
    all_combinations.append(list(zipped))

print(all_combinations)
```

Output

```
[[('a', 1), ('b', 2)], [('a', 1), ('c', 2)], [('b', 1), ('a', 2)], [('b', 1), ('c', 2)], [('c', 1), ('a', 2)], [('c', 1), ('b', 2)]]
```